# How to collate all input from the console

Tags: scala

I would like to read a line of input from the console and convert that to a list of strings. I tried this:

```
   val foo: Iterator[List[String]] =  for(ln <- io.Source.stdin.getLines ) yield ln.split(" ")
```

But the type of `foo` is `Iterator[List[String]]` whereas I would like `List[String]`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `io.StdIn.readLine().split(' ')` is all you need.  Result is `Array[String]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by 'list of strings' you actually mean **words** then as @jwvh stated it would be simply:

```
scala> val input = scala.io.StdIn.readLine().split(' ').toList
input: List[String] = List(This, is, a, test)
```

Or is you want list...